# VBA: Converting Dictionary into Array to speed process

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary

I have created a dictionary with over 4000 keys and several items, however passing this dictionary onto a sheet is very time consuming and inefficient. I have researched this and it seems passing to an array then dictionary will be faster due to the use memory which makes sense.

The Procedure is called using below.

```
Sub Dictionary()

Dim dict As Dictionary

Set dict = ReadData()

Call WriteDict(dict)

End Sub
```

This creates the dictionary and fills the custom class module

```
Function ReadData()


Dim dict As New Dictionary

Dim DataWs As Worksheet: Set DataWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")
Dim PoolOfWeekWs As Worksheet: Set PoolOfWeekWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pool of the week")

Dim range As range: Set range = DataWs.range("A1").CurrentRegion

Dim i As Long
Dim CandidateProcessID As String, CandidateName As String, FirstName As String, ProcessStatus As String, FirstITWDate As String, PQLDate As String, XP As String, oCandidate As ClsCandidate

For i = 2 To range.Rows.Count
    If range.Cells(i, 35).Value <> "NOK" Then
    
        ProcessStatus = range.Cells(i, 9).Value
        If range.Cells(i, 13).Value = "Prequalification" Then PQLDate = range.Cells(i, 11).Value
        ProcessType = range.Cells(i, 35).Value
        InterviewScore = range.Cells(i, 37).Value
        CandidateName = range.Cells(i, 16).Value
        FirstName = range.Cells(i, 17).Value
        NameofCM = range.Cells(i, 44).Value
        If range.Cells(i, 13) = "Candidate Interview 1" Then FirstITWDate = range.Cells(i, 11).Value
        BM1ITW = range.Cells(i, 44).Value
        DetailedSkills = range.Cells(i, 28).Value
        SkillsSummary = range.Cells(i, 29).Value
        Sector = range.Cells(i, 49).Value
        XP = range.Cells(i, 24).Value
        NP = range.Cells(i, 30).Value
        Nationality = range.Cells(i, 39).Value
        SalaryExpectation = range.Cells(i, 48).Value
        ProposedSalary = range.Cells(i, 48).Value
        If range.Cells(i, 13) = "Candidate Interview 2+" Then SecondITWDate = range.Cells(i, 11).Value
        If range.Cells(i, 13) = "Candidate Interview 2*" Then PPLDate = range.Cells(i, 11).Value
        Email = range.Cells(i, 18).Value
        PhoneNum = range.Cells(i, 19).Value
        ROName = range.Cells(i, 46).Value
        'BusinessUnitName
        'RecruitmentOfficerBusinessUnit
        'RecruiterTreegram
        'LookupyearsExperience
        
        CandidateProcessID = range.Cells(i, 10).Value
        
        If range.Cells(i, 13) = "Signature Interview" Then SignatureInterview = range.Cells(i, 11).Value
             
    If dict.Exists(CandidateProcessID) = True Then
        Set oCandidate = dict(CandidateProcessID)
        
        oCandidate.ProcessStatus = oCandidate.ProcessStatus
        oCandidate.PQLDate = oCandidate.PQLDate
        oCandidate.ProcessType = oCandidate.ProcessType
        oCandidate.InterviewScore = oCandidate.InterviewScore
        oCandidate.CandidateName = oCandidate.CandidateName
        oCandidate.FirstName = oCandidate.FirstName
        oCandidate.NameofCM = oCandidate.NameofCM
        oCandidate.FirstITWDate = oCandidate.FirstITWDate
        oCandidate.BM1ITW = oCandidate.BM1ITW
        oCandidate.DetailedSkills = oCandidate.DetailedSkills
        oCandidate.SkillsSummary = oCandidate.SkillsSummary
        oCandidate.Sector = oCandidate.Sector
        oCandidate.YearsExp = oCandidate.YearsExp
        oCandidate.NP = oCandidate.NP
        oCandidate.Nationality = oCandidate.Nationality
        oCandidate.SalaryExpectation = oCandidate.SalaryExpectation
        oCandidate.ProposedSalary = oCandidate.ProposedSalary
        oCandidate.SecondITWDate = oCandidate.SecondITWDate
        oCandidate.PPLDate = oCandidate.PPLDate
        oCandidate.Email = oCandidate.Email
        oCandidate.PhoneNum = oCandidate.PhoneNum
        oCandidate.ROName = oCandidate.ROName
       
    Else
        Set oCandidate = New ClsCandidate
        dict.Add CandidateProcessID, oCandidate
        
        oCandidate.ProcessStatus = oCandidate.ProcessStatus + ProcessStatus
        oCandidate.PQLDate = oCandidate.PQLDate + PQLDate
        oCandidate.ProcessType = oCandidate.ProcessType + ProcessType
        oCandidate.InterviewScore = oCandidate.InterviewScore + InterviewScore
        oCandidate.CandidateName = oCandidate.CandidateName + CandidateName
        oCandidate.FirstName = oCandidate.FirstName + FirstName
        oCandidate.NameofCM = oCandidate.NameofCM + NameofCM
        oCandidate.FirstITWDate = oCandidate.FirstITWDate + FirstITWDate
        oCandidate.BM1ITW = oCandidate.BM1ITW + BM1ITW
        oCandidate.DetailedSkills = oCandidate.DetailedSkills + DetailedSkills
        oCandidate.SkillsSummary = oCandidate.SkillsSummary + SkillsSummary
        oCandidate.Sector = oCandidate.Sector + Sector
        oCandidate.YearsExp = oCandidate.YearsExp + YearsExp
        oCandidate.NP = oCandidate.NP + NP
        oCandidate.Nationality = oCandidate.Nationality + Nationality
        oCandidate.SalaryExpectation = oCandidate.SalaryExpectation + SalaryExpectation
        oCandidate.ProposedSalary = oCandidate.ProposedSalary + ProposedSalary
        oCandidate.SecondITWDate = oCandidate.SecondITWDate + SecondITWDate
        oCandidate.PPLDate = oCandidate.PPLDate + PPLDate
        oCandidate.Email = oCandidate.Email + Email
        oCandidate.PhoneNum = oCandidate.PhoneNum + PhoneNum
        oCandidate.ROName = oCandidate.ROName + ROName
    End If
    
    End If

Next i

Set ReadData = dict


End Function
```

Below writes the data to the sheet

```
Sub WriteDict(dict As Dictionary)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim key, DictOutput() As Variant, oCandidate As ClsCandidate, row, TotalEntries, TotalColumns As Long, OutputRange As range
    Set rangeoutput = Sheets("Pool of the week")
    row = 1
    
    TotalEntries = dict.Count
    TotalColumns = 22
    DictOutput = dict.Items()
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Firstly, i tried to pass the dictionary to an array simply by using the above method. However it does not add the dictionary items from the class module in the same order (In alphabetical) as the dictionary, which was one of the reasons I created the dictionary in the first place to rearrange them.

Is there away to get the array to keep the same format as the dictionary, and if so, what's the best way to pass to the sheet now? Would it just be

```
'Psuedo code
Sheets(SHEETNAME).Range("A1").Resize(UBound(DictOutput(1)) = DictOutput
```

**After Comment**
The Array seems to be one dimension as shown in screenshot. Also not in correct order
[Screenshot of Array Crated from Dictionary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehGnU.png)

**EDIT AFTER ANSWER**

```
For i = 2 To range.Rows.Count
    If range.Cells(i, 35).Value <> "NOK" Then
    
        If range.Cells(i, 13) = "Candidate Interview 1" Then FirstITWDate = range.Cells(i, 11).Value: BM1ITW = range.Cells(i, 5).Value
        If range.Cells(i, 49) = "Expected Gross Annual Salary" Then SalaryExpectation = range.Cells(i, 50).Value ' If column x is salary expectation take this value
        If range.Cells(i, 49) = "Proposed Gross Annual Salary (AHF)" Then ProposedSalary = range.Cells(i, 50).Value 'if column x is proposed take this value
        If range.Cells(i, 13) = "Candidate Interview 2+" Then SecondITWDate = range.Cells(i, 11).Value
        If range.Cells(i, 13) = "Candidate Interview 2*" Then PPLDate = range.Cells(i, 11).Value
        If range.Cells(i, 13).Value = "Prequalification" Then PQLDate = range.Cells(i, 11).Value
        If range.Cells(i, 13) = "Signature Interview" Then SignatureInterview = range.Cells(i, 11).Value
        
        CandidateProcessID = range.Cells(i, 10).Value
        ProcessStatus = range.Cells(i, 9).Value
        ProcessType = range.Cells(i, 35).Value
        InterviewScore = range.Cells(i, 37).Value
        CandidateName = range.Cells(i, 16).Value
        FirstName = range.Cells(i, 17).Value
        NameofCM = range.Cells(i, 44).Value
        DetailedSkills = range.Cells(i, 28).Value
        SkillsSummary = range.Cells(i, 29).Value
        Sector = range.Cells(i, 48).Value
        XP = range.Cells(i, 24).Value
        NP = range.Cells(i, 30).Value
        Nationality = range.Cells(i, 39).Value
        Mobility = range.Cells(i, 47).Value
        Email = range.Cells(i, 18).Value
        PhoneNum = range.Cells(i, 19).Value
        ROName = range.Cells(i, 46).Value
        
        'BusinessUnitName
        'RecruitmentOfficerBusinessUnit
        'RecruiterTreegram
        'LookupyearsExperience
        
        
        
        If dict.Exists(CandidateProcessID) = True Then
            Set oCandidate = dict(CandidateProcessID)
                oCandidate.ProcessStatus = ProcessStatus
                oCandidate.PQLDate = PQLDate
                oCandidate.ProcessType = ProcessType
                oCandidate.InterviewScore = InterviewScore
                oCandidate.CandidateName = CandidateName
                oCandidate.FirstName = FirstName
                oCandidate.NameofCM = NameofCM
                oCandidate.FirstITWDate = FirstITWDate
                oCandidate.BM1ITW = BM1ITW
                oCandidate.DetailedSkills = DetailedSkills
                oCandidate.SkillsSummary = SkillsSummary
                oCandidate.Sector = Sector
                oCandidate.YearsExp = YearsExp
                oCandidate.NP = NP
                oCandidate.Nationality = Nationality
                oCandidate.Mobility = Mobility
                oCandidate.SalaryExpectation = SalaryExpectation
                oCandidate.ProposedSalary = ProposedSalary
                oCandidate.SecondITWDate = SecondITWDate
                oCandidate.PPLDate = PPLDate
                oCandidate.Email = Email
                oCandidate.PhoneNum = PhoneNum
                oCandidate.ROName = ROName
        Else
            Set oCandidate = New ClsCandidate

                oCandidate.ProcessStatus = ProcessStatus
                oCandidate.PQLDate = PQLDate
                oCandidate.ProcessType = ProcessType
                oCandidate.InterviewScore = InterviewScore
                oCandidate.CandidateName = CandidateName
                oCandidate.FirstName = FirstName
                oCandidate.NameofCM = NameofCM
                oCandidate.FirstITWDate = FirstITWDate
                oCandidate.BM1ITW = BM1ITW
                oCandidate.DetailedSkills = DetailedSkills
                oCandidate.SkillsSummary = SkillsSummary
                oCandidate.Sector = Sector
                oCandidate.YearsExp = YearsExp
                oCandidate.NP = NP
                oCandidate.Nationality = Nationality
                oCandidate.Mobility = Mobility
                oCandidate.SalaryExpectation = SalaryExpectation
                oCandidate.ProposedSalary = ProposedSalary
                oCandidate.SecondITWDate = SecondITWDate
                oCandidate.PPLDate = PPLDate
                oCandidate.Email = Email
                oCandidate.PhoneNum = PhoneNum
                oCandidate.ROName = ROName
        
            dict.Add CandidateProcessID, oCandidate
        End If
        
    End If

Next i
```

Comment: You can't write an array of custom objects to a worksheet like that: you'd need to loop over the array, extract each object's properties one-by-one, and write them to the row for that object.

Comment: Why do you need to use a custom class?

Comment: @TimWilliams would looping over array be more costly that print dictionary to sheets? It will be a large array

Comment: @freeflow I used a custom class as theres multiple entries for one person, but the in same column could be equal to a different thing depending on entry event so thought it was easier to do so

Comment: You don't really have any choice.

Comment: @0Marine0  That just means you use a dictionary of dictionaries.  However as you don't clearly explain your data structure.....

Comment: FYI in `ReadData` you're still making the same mistake from your previous post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64125396/excel-vba-class-module-variables-value-location-depending-on-if-function   If there's an existing candidate in the dictionary then you just set the object properties to their current values (which basically does nothing).  However when you make a new object you *add* to the existing properties (which at that point will all be *empty*)

Comment: @TimWilliams I am still a little confused as i was before. So i can remove the lines where it sets the object properties to their current values (As it does nothing). But i need the second part of fill the variables for the class?

Comment: Maybe try cutting that down to something a lot simpler?  Just create a test calls with a few properties - it will be easier to reason about your code when there's a lot less of it.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing how you're populating your dictionary: your logic is not correct, and should be something like this:

```text
loop over lines
    read data from the line
    if object with line's "key" exists in the dictionary
        get reference to existing object from dictionary
        append additional information to the object's properties
    else
        create new object
        populate properties
        add to dictionary
    end if
next line
```

Comment: Okay i am trying to strip the code back to understand the logic. But so far, the solution is escaping me. So far what i think i am doing is see if key exists, if it does, append values. If it doesnt, add key and then append values. Would a solution be to do the If exists, dont add, else add key to dictionay, end if, then append all data? See edit for reference

Comment: FYI, i know something is wrong as the data is half correct when inputting into sheet. Some data replaces with another candidates info so i know you are right